# Retrieve Lastest Date from SQL and Get Difference

Tags: mysql, datetime

My Tables are :

**QuestionMaster**

`+-----+---------------------+
|qId  |quesDate             |
+-----+---------------------+
|1    |2014-02-04 06:12:10  |
+-----+---------------------+
|2    |2014-02-05 18:46:15  |
+-----+---------------------+
|3    |2014-02-05 08:06:05  |
+-----+------+--------------+`

**AnswerMaster**

`+--------+------+---------------------+
|answerId|quesId|answerDate           |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|1       |1     |2014-02-08 11:10:05  |
+-----------+------+------------------+
|2       |1     |2014-02-10 18:06:05  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|3       |1     |2014-02-07 12:07:10  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|4       |2     |2014-02-09 09:18:05  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|5       |2     |2014-03-01 08:06:05  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|6       |2     |2014-02-15 16:10:45  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|7       |2     |2014-02-12 06:35:25  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|8       |3     |2014-03-05 08:09:05  |
+--------+------+---------------------+
|9       |3     |2014-02-25 15:02:19  |
+--------+------+---------------------+`

I want difference in days for latest answer date for a specific question. I have tried this query.
I don't want to use subquery.

```
SELECT 
question.qid as questionId,
timestampdiff(DAY,question.quesDate,answer.answerDate) AS `answerTime`
FROM QuestionMaster question
Left Join AnswerMaster answer on question.qid = answer.quesid
group by question.qid ;
```

Expected output is:

`+-----+-----------------+
|qId  |DifferenceInDays |
+-----+-----------------+
|1    |6                |
+-----+-----------------+
|2    |23               |
+-----+-----------------+
|3    |28               |
+-----+-----------------+`

Any suggestion ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I used GROUP BY in that context, I'd have no idea what to expect

Comment: "I don't want to use subqueries?" Are you serious? You've chosen a language and technology that works a certain way, and yet you don't want to use it? Do you have a reason for this?

Comment: This is just a part of my actual query. That's why there may have performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the `MAX(answerDate)`, else MySQL will use the value of some indeterminate record within each group.

```
SELECT   q.qId, DATEDIFF(MAX(a.answerDate), q.quesDate)
FROM     QuestionMaster q JOIN AnswerMaster a ON a.quesId = q.qId
GROUP BY q.qId
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49e21/2/0).